# How can I return a string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code that performs a query.

```
int credenciadaId = 10;
var nome = from c in db.SanCredenciadas
           where c.CredenciadaId == credenciadaId
           select c.Name;
```

My question is in 2 parts.

I want the query to return just one `Name` as a `string`. How can I change the query `nome` so the following code would be valid?

```
string name = nome;
```

Additionally, how can I write the improved query so that it uses lambda expression(s) and the [method syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) rather than the current query syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this

```
string name = nome.Single().Name;
```

This will fail if you don't get one result which I suspect is what you want.

Your query using a lambda would be

```
var credenciadaId = 10;
var name = db.San_Credenciadas
    .Single(c => c.Credenciada_Id == credenciadaId).Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = db.San_Credenciadas.First(c => c.Credenciada_Id == Credenciada_Id).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that if you're going to use `collection.Single()` or `collection.Single(x => x.Onething == someValue)` that your collection MUST have a single item that matches that, or it'll throw an exception.

As for `collection.First()`, you simply want to make sure that `collection` actually has some data, so you could, for example, use `if (collection.Any())`

Generally, I'd opt for using `collection.SingleOrDefault()` or `collection.FirstOrDefault()` then checking if the value returned from that isn't null. If not, then you can get the name. If it *is* null, then you can handle the error as needed.